# How to work with ldap in .net C#

Tags: c#, email, ldap

I have an application where i can send emails. Now am asked to use ldap in to and from fields of the email.Am very new to this concept. I have been given a ldap link. No idea how to proceed with that. Any aricle or hits will be greatly helpful.

Comment: What is the relation between LDAP and the email fields? To and From are only text fields that contains an standardized email address. It looks like someone gave you a requirement without understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up and using Microsoft's **Active Directory** as your LDAP store, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here, e.g. get the user's e-mail address(es)
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the functionality I've used is in System.DirectoryServices.

Have a look at this link for more info: http://lozanotek.com/blog/articles/149.aspx

The LDAP link is basically a reference to a directory server, such as Active Directory, which will give you email addresses if you have their user name, for example.  I'd start off by reading the article above, then experimenting with a small test program

Comment: I'd double-check your requirements... the directory contains all the information about the users in the system, along with their email address.  If you've been asked to add email addresses - which for a program that can send emails sounds strange - you'll likely need to create users too, which can be complex

Comment: The req is ..i have a to textbox to type in the email address. next to it i have search button.the email address i type must be searched in ldap server . if not i should get a error saying the mail id does not exist.

Comment: Ah OK... sound like you won't actually be adding new accounts into the directory server then.  Try this [link]:(http://snipplr.com/view/43817/)

Comment: Its a web application and not windows.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean it's a web application and not a Windows service (which shouldn't make a difference), or it's not running on Windows (the title says you're using C#)?

Comment: k then how do i use the method' public static string GetSAMAccountNameByEmail(string email)'on button click event protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { GetSAMAccountNameByEmail("123@gmail.com"); } is it this way?

Comment: In the btn_Click event, you should be able to get a reference to the textbox and get the string from that, then pass it to the GetSAMAccountNameByEmail function

Comment: yeag rite..got really confused wid this ldap and forgot basics. thank you